# Filtering values from generator object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this generator type data.

```
type(head)
----------
generator
```

Its values looks like this

```
for x in head:
    print(x)
```

---

```
  Record {
  field1         '2022060611121280041700000070046713963'
  field2         '2022-06-06 01:11:29'
  field3         'NIL'
  }
```

I'm thinking if it's possible to convert this to data frame? I could probably create a script that would loop the content of Record but I'm hoping there's a much cleaner way.

Comment: can you provide the code to generate `head`?

Comment: @mozway, hi. it's coming from this python library that I'm using. 
https://pyodps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/base-tables.html

basically what it does it gets the first N rows from the table.

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to make reproducible example since you'd have to access an odps database to be able to generate that result. That's why I only posted the "Record" result.

Comment: have you tried https://pyodps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-df.html#odps.df.DataFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the generated contents fit into memory, then `pandas` can consume it:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame

# head is a generator
df = DataFrame([x for x in head])
```

If the contents of the generator are too large, then you can iterate over chunks of data (using [toolz](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)) and store each chunk, e.g. to `csv`:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame
from toolz import partition_all

n_elements = 100

for n, x in enumerate(partition_all(n_elements, head)):
    df = DataFrame(x)
    if n==0:
        df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False, mode='w')
    else:
        df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False, mode='a', header=False)
```

Comment: I've tried the first solution but its returning 'generator' object is not callable. I've removed the () from head. There's no error but df is empty.

Comment: Sorry, yes, the () brackets are not needed.

Comment: Can you write what you get if you run: `for x in head: print(type(x))`?

Comment: Apologies. It’s not empty. I was just not able to initialize the population of head. Your solution worked fine. Thank you.